# spring-boot3 on aws lambda failure

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda

im using the "kotless" library which is kinda dead so im trying to update it to support spring-boot 3 myself.

the relevant commit can be found here if relevant https://github.com/JetBrains/kotless/pull/128/commits/f077223d2f81f0e622bdcb45f635d73ec4d20503

i have configured the following deps:

```
"com.amazonaws.serverless:aws-serverless-java-container-springboot3:2.0.0-M2"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.2.0"
```

simplified main (without kotless) looks like the following:

```
package com.playground

import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.InitializationWrapper
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.model.AwsProxyRequest
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder
import com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.embedded.ServerlessServletEmbeddedServerFactory
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestStreamHandler
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.OutputStream

@SpringBootApplication
open class Application : RequestStreamHandler {
    val handler by lazy {
        SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder<AwsProxyRequest>()
            .defaultProxy()
            .initializationWrapper(InitializationWrapper())
            .springBootApplication(Application::class.java)
            .profiles()
            .buildAndInitialize()
    }

    override fun handleRequest(input: InputStream, output: OutputStream, context: Context) {
        handler

        val json = input.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

        if (json.contains("Scheduled Event")) {
            return
        }
        handler.proxyStream(json.byteInputStream(), output, context)
    }
}
```

tho its seems like the lambda doesnt pick up the embedded servlet therefore recognize my application as
"AnnotationConfigApplicationContext".

```
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.0)
19:33:24.536 [main] INFO com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda -- Starting AWSLambda v2.4.1 using Java 17.0.8.1 with PID 8 (/var/runtime/lib/aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client-2.4.1-linux-x86_64.jar started by sbx_user1051 in /var/task)
19:33:24.536 [main] INFO com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
19:33:25.154 [main] INFO com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.AWSLambda -- Started AWSLambda in 0.621 seconds (process running for 187.847)
class org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext cannot be cast to class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext and org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext are in unnamed module of loader com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.CustomerClassLoader @1ddc4ec2): java.lang.ClassCastException
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext cannot be cast to class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext (org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext and org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext are in unnamed module of loader com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.api.client.CustomerClassLoader @1ddc4ec2)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.initialize(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:191)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.InitializationWrapper.start(InitializationWrapper.java:35)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder.buildAndInitialize(SpringBootProxyHandlerBuilder.java:79)
    at com.amazonaws.serverless.proxy.spring.SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.java:87)
    at io.kotless.dsl.spring.Kotless.handleRequest(Kotless.kt:35)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

the same flow works just fine with

```
"com.amazonaws.serverless:aws-serverless-java-container-springboot1.5.2"
"org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.4.2"
```

oh and one last note -> when i try to run it locally it doesnt throw errors

i tried to upgrade from spring-boot 2 to 3 expecting the lambda to work with embeded servlet but it is actually failing.

**edit:**
playing with spring-boot code i found the exact class that caused me troubles (not sure why yet) and i replace it with a prev logic which end up working. i still wonder why the original setup doesnt work well for me tho.

here is the class after my adjustments

```html
/*
 * Copyright 2012-2023 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.springframework.boot;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

/**
 * Strategy interface for creating the {@link ConfigurableApplicationContext} used by a
 * {@link SpringApplication}. Created contexts should be returned in their default form,
 * with the {@code SpringApplication} responsible for configuring and refreshing the
 * context.
 *
 * @author Andy Wilkinson
 * @author Phillip Webb
 * @since 2.4.0
 */
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ApplicationContextFactory {

    /**
     * A default {@link ApplicationContextFactory} implementation that will create an
     * appropriate context for the {@link WebApplicationType}.
     */
   
  //marking out the DEFAULT behaviour and replacing it with logic from 2.5.12 which works for me
    //ApplicationContextFactory DEFAULT = new DefaultApplicationContextFactory();
    ApplicationContextFactory DEFAULT = (webApplicationType) -> {
        try {
            switch (webApplicationType) {
                case SERVLET:
                    return new AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext();
                case REACTIVE:
                    return new AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext();
                default:
                    return new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable create a default ApplicationContext instance, "
                    + "you may need a custom ApplicationContextFactory", ex);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Return the {@link Environment} type expected to be set on the
     * {@link #create(WebApplicationType) created} application context. The result of this
     * method can be used to convert an existing environment instance to the correct type.
     * @param webApplicationType the web application type
     * @return the expected application context type or {@code null} to use the default
     * @since 2.6.14
     */
    default Class<? extends ConfigurableEnvironment> getEnvironmentType(WebApplicationType webApplicationType) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new {@link Environment} to be set on the
     * {@link #create(WebApplicationType) created} application context. The result of this
     * method must match the type returned by
     * {@link #getEnvironmentType(WebApplicationType)}.
     * @param webApplicationType the web application type
     * @return an environment instance or {@code null} to use the default
     * @since 2.6.14
     */
    default ConfigurableEnvironment createEnvironment(WebApplicationType webApplicationType) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the {@link ConfigurableApplicationContext application context} for a
     * {@link SpringApplication}, respecting the given {@code webApplicationType}.
     * @param webApplicationType the web application type
     * @return the newly created application context
     */
    ConfigurableApplicationContext create(WebApplicationType webApplicationType);

    /**
     * Creates an {@code ApplicationContextFactory} that will create contexts by
     * instantiating the given {@code contextClass} through its primary constructor.
     * @param contextClass the context class
     * @return the factory that will instantiate the context class
     * @see BeanUtils#instantiateClass(Class)
     */
    static ApplicationContextFactory ofContextClass(Class<? extends ConfigurableApplicationContext> contextClass) {
        return of(() -> BeanUtils.instantiateClass(contextClass));
    }

    /**
     * Creates an {@code ApplicationContextFactory} that will create contexts by calling
     * the given {@link Supplier}.
     * @param supplier the context supplier, for example
     * {@code AnnotationConfigApplicationContext::new}
     * @return the factory that will instantiate the context class
     */
    static ApplicationContextFactory of(Supplier<ConfigurableApplicationContext> supplier) {
        return (webApplicationType) -> supplier.get();
    }

}
```

to override the class i simply added it to the project

Comment: i managed to pin it down a bit closer.


force("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.5.12") - works while 2.5.13 fails